# leftOuterJoin throws TableException: Unsupported join type 'LEFT'

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-sql

I'm trying to run a left outer join on two tables and convert the results to a DataStream.

All the joins I've done before using flink have been inner joins, and I have always followed the join with a `.toRetractStream[MyCaseClass](someQueryConfig)`.  However, with the introduction of null values due to the left join, my understanding from the [flink docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/table/common.html#convert-a-table-into-a-datastream-or-dataset) is that I can no longer use case classes because they don't support null values when converting a table to a DataStream.

So, I'm trying to accomplish this using a POJO. Here is my code:

```
class EnrichedTaskUpdateJoin(val enrichedTaskId: String, val enrichedTaskJobId: String, val enrichedTaskJobDate: String, val enrichedTaskJobMetadata: Json, val enrichedTaskStartedAt: String, val enrichedTaskTaskMetadata: Json, val taskUpdateMetadata: Json = Json.Null) {}

val qConfig = tableEnv.queryConfig
qConfig.withIdleStateRetentionTime(IDLE_STATE_RETENTION_TIME)

val updatedTasksUpsertTable = enrichedTasksUpsertTable
  .leftOuterJoin(taskUpdatesUpsertTable, 'enrichedTaskId === 'taskUpdateId)
  .select(
    'enrichedTaskId,
    'enrichedTaskJobId,
    'enrichedTaskJobDate,
    'enrichedTaskJobMetadata,
    'enrichedTaskStartedAt,
    'enrichedTaskTaskMetadata,
    'taskUpdateMetadata
  )

val updatedEnrichedTasksStream: KeyedStream[String, String] = updatedTasksUpsertTable
  .toAppendStream[EnrichedTaskUpdateJoin](qConfig)
  .map(toEnrichedTask(_))
  .map(encodeTask(_))
  .keyBy(x => parse(x).getOrElse(Json.Null).hcursor.get[String]("id").getOrElse(""))
```

This compiles just fine, but when I try to run it, I get `org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Unsupported join type 'LEFT'. Currently only non-window inner joins with at least one equality predicate are supported`. However, according to [these docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/table/tableApi.html#joins), it seems like I should be able to run a left join.  It also seems worth noting that the error gets thrown from the `.toAppendStream[EnrichedTaskUpdateJoin](qConfig)`.
I thought perhaps the `non-window` portion of the error implied that my idle state retention time was a problem, so I took the query config out, but got the same error.

Hopefully this has enough context, but if I need to add anything else please let me know. Also, I'm running flink 1.5-SNAPSHOT and Circe for json parsing.  I'm also quite new to scala, so it's very possible that this is just some dumb syntax error.

Comment: You are running a SNAPSHOT version. Flink 1.5.1 was released a few days ago. Can you try to run the query on this version? If this does not work, it looks like a bug that should be reported to the project via mailing list or Jira. Thank you.

Comment: @FabianHueske, so is this supported in 1.5? Because twlalthr was saying I'd have to move up to version 1.6.

Comment: Oh, yes. Got confused with the versions. Non-windowed outer joins will be released with 1.6.0 which is currently being prepared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-windowed outer joins are not supported in Flink 1.5-SNAPSHOT. As you can see in the link that you have posted, there is no "Streaming" tag next to "Outer Joins". Time-windowed joins (which work on time attributes) were supported in 1.5.

Flink 1.6 will provide `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, and `FULL` outer joins (see also [FLINK-5878](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-5878)).

Btw. make sure that `EnrichedTaskUpdateJoin` is really a POJO because POJOs need a default constructor and I think also `var` instead of `val`.

Comment: I thought that might have been the case, but there also isn't a "Streaming" tag next to the "Inner Join", but the inner joins seem to work just fine. Any thoughts on why that might be?
Thanks a ton for the quick response.  Really appreciate it.

Comment: I see a "Streaming" tag next to inner join.

Comment: Looks like there's a "streaming" tag when you have Java selected, but not when you have Scala selected.  Or am I maybe looking at the wrong thing?

Comment: Good point. The tag for Scala is missing. I will fix that! Thank you.